# Delphi DLL Modal Form causes AV on Second Call

Tags: forms, delphi, dll

I am trying to show a modal (FMX) form from a DLL. Eventually this will be ported to OSX so I'm trying to keep the 'Windows' code to a minimum. Based on what's in the forum I have tried to keep the code as simple possible.

I know that the first time showmodal is called, the code works as expected, but if I subsequently call the DLL function, I get an AV trying to create the form. I then tried to (without exiting the function) create and free the form several times, this works without issue. And it works if I call the function, create and free the form and DO NOT showmodal. In all my tests, if I showmodal I get the AV trying to create the form the second time and the application hangs.

Of course, if I just show the form I do not get the issue, ie. I can create the form, show it and free it in a loop and it works fine. The issue is of course that the code just continues through destroying the form and I need the form to be modal.

THE DLL EMPSECURE_UI.DLL

```
function dAbout_UI:boolean; {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}stdcall{$ELSE}cdecl{$ENDIF} export;
var
  dAbout: TfAbout;

begin
  try
    try
      Result := True;

      dAbout := TfAbout.Create(nil);  
      dAbout.Showmodal;
    except
        Result := False;
    end;
  finally
    FreeandNil(dAbout);
  end;
```

The UNIT in the ABOUT Form

```
procedure TfAbout.bOKClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ModalResult := mrOK;
  Close;
end;

procedure TfAbout.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin

  Action := System.UITypes.TCloseAction.caFree;
end;
```

The Test program that calls the function in the DLL  uTESTEMPSECURE_UI.pas, ie. the main program, the simple call to the function that displays the modal form:

```
const
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  EMPSecureUI = 'empsecure_ui.dll';
  {$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}
  {$IFDEF MACOS}
  EMPSecureUI = 'libempsecure_ui.dylib';
  {$ENDIF MACOS}

// EMPSecure_UI Functions
function dAbout_UI: boolean; {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}stdcall{$ELSE}cdecl{$ENDIF}; external EMPSecureUI;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  dAbout_UI;
end;
```

So the first time I run this code and call the function which shows the modal form it works as expected, a modal form is shown. When I click OK on the form, the form is freed and control is returned to the main test program. This is exactly as expected.

If I then execute a second call to the DLL function an AV occurs when trying to create the form the second time. IF, OTOH, the form is simply shown (not modal), no AV occurs when I try to create the form a second or subsequent time.

Comment: I haven't done a dll dialog in delphi in years, BUT I did check my code. Given the order of what's happening, I'm not sure this is the issue, but I think you should use dAbout.release instead of FreeAndNil. Also, what happens if you add a WriteLog to the line before FreeAndNil. Is it getting there?

Comment: @DonDickinson: No, Release instead won't help. Neither does FreeAndNil, as it's a local variable being used. There's too much irrelevant content here. The pattern should be `SomeVar := TSomething.Create(nil); try SomveVar.ShowModal; finally SomeVar.Free; end;`. There is no need to FreeAndNil a local variable, and there is no need to use Release for a modal form.

Comment: What you are doing is jot supported. Use packages instead.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Packages not an option since this needs to be accessed on macOS by a SWIFT application, ie. I'm just writing some quick and simple (I Thought) UI code in a DYLIB to pop a couple of forms (and perhaps pass back one or two variables). When you say not supported, what exactly isn't supported?

Comment: @kenWhite Not sure what you mean by irrelevant content. The code actually does do what you suggest create/showmodal/free. The rest of the code is minor logging and exception handling, but it's fairly obvious where those three things occur I would have thought.

Comment: Having said all of the above, your code is confused. It doesn't help when you post the code *after* you trial and error session. Remove FormClose. Set ModalResult in the button OnClick handler.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan WRT confusing code, perhaps you might like to suggest how I should present it. Regardless I have removed the logging statements etc. WRT post after trial and error: I have no idea what you mean. Are you suggesting I shouldn't try to get the code to work before asking the question? That seems counterintuitive. I moved the set modal result as you suggest. I have further moved the code segments into their own section so you can more readily see the code associated with the: 1. DLL 2. Form 3. Test app.

Comment: I said to remove the setting of Action. Do that. You free the form externally. Get rid of the form OnClose event. Don't call Close. It's enough to set ModalResult. Also, your try/finally logic is wrong.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you for clarifying your earlier comment.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I have incorporated your changes and now the forms appear and disappear as expected, thank you for the sage advice. I have one issue and may raise another question: For an edit box on a form created in from the  DLL, there is no Caret which makes it difficult to enter data. Again, not wishing to conflate issues and not wishing to offend the keepers of stack overflow, should I ask a separate question or edit my original question?

Comment: New question.....