# Delphi Modal Form from DLL: Edit Field(s) have no Caret - How to show Caret?

Tags: forms, delphi, dll

I have a Delphi DLL that has a function that creates and displays a modal form. After some grief and assistance from the forum I now get that form to display consistently and correctly when the DLL / function is called by the test application. Here is the discussion surrounding that:
[Delphi DLL Modal Form Causes AV on Second Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57228715/delphi-dll-modal-form-causes-av-on-second-call?noredirect=1#comment100962632_57228715)

The form displayed has a couple of edit fields. Whilst these fields do get focus, however when entering data there is no caret. I have, in the design part, ensured that here is a caret, but none is ever displayed which makes it difficult to enter data. Regardless, and without the caret, the data is entered correctly.

I have tried several different edit field components other than the standard Delphi one. All exhibit the same behaviour, ie. no caret if the field is on a modal form that was created by a DLL. All the fields correctly display the caret if placed on the main form of the calling test application (as expected).

This is the function within the DLL that displays the modal form (correctly). The two fields are simply text fields (in this case a userID and Password, but that is irrelevant). The function works and retrieves the data from the two fields and passes that data back through the 'out' parameters to the main calling application.

````
```
// EMPSecure_UI Functions
function dLogin_UI(out UserID: pChar; out Password: pChar): boolean; {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}stdcall{$ELSE}cdecl{$ENDIF}; forward;
function dAbout_UI: boolean; {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}stdcall{$ELSE}cdecl{$ENDIF}; forward;
```
exports
  dLogin_UI, //{$IFDEF MACOS}name '_dLogin_UI'{$ENDIF},
  dAbout_UI; //{$IFDEF MACOS}name '_dAbout_UI'{$ENDIF},
```
var
  // Forms
  dAbout: TfAbout;
  dLogin: TfLogin;

```
    function dLogin_UI(out UserID: pChar; out Password: pChar):boolean; {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}stdcall{$ELSE}cdecl{$ENDIF} export;
    begin
      Result := True;
      UserID := '';
      Password := '';

      if not(Assigned(dLogin)) then
        dLogin := TfLogin.Create(nil);
      dLogin.ShowModal;  

      UserID := pChar(dLogin.eUserID.Text);
      Password := pChar(dLogin.ePassword.Text);

    end;
```
````

Since there are two simple edit fields, I'd expect the caret to be visible in each when it has focus and data is being entered. It simply isn't, data entry occurs, but without the caret and there are no errors that I can find.

Comment: I'm still pretty much convinced that using DLLs to host UI is full of pitfalls in FMX.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I am becoming very much of that view. In fact FMX on OSX is immature and probably not really where you should be from a development perspective. Delphi VCL on windows fine, but cross platform? My colleague has taken the burden of OSX development (including UI now) using SWIFT (he's a C++ programmer) and it just works (sorry).